# Select all nodes with attribute using xpath

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I am trying to select all nodes using `root.SelectNodes()` with `XPath`. For reference, see [msdn-documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hcebdtae.aspx).

In the [following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4001277/xpath-expression-for-selecting-all-nodes-with-a-common-attribute) document explained, you can also search for nodes that contain attributes (correct me if this is actually a wrong understanding).

So I used the following line of code:

```
XmlNodeList nodes = projectDoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("descendant::Compile[attribute::Include]");
```

And I am trying to read the following data:

```
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion="4.0">
    <ItemGroup>
        <Compile Include="ArrayExtensions.cs" />
        <Compile Include="ArrayIterator.cs" />
        <Compile Include="AutoInitializeAttribute.cs" />
        <Compile Include="AutoInitializePriority.cs" />
        <Compile Include="AutoRegisterAttribute.cs" />
        <Compile Include="FormattableExtensions.cs" />
        <Compile Include="Mathematics\PrimeNumbers.cs" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

As shown in the code-sample above, I want to get all the XmlNodes that contain the Include-attribute. However, when I execute my code, `nodes` contains 0 elements.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I strongly suspect that the problem is the namespace - you should actually be looking for `Compile` elements in the `http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003` namespace. Is there any reason you need to do this in XPath? With LINQ to XML this would be trivial.

Comment: No particular reason no, if you have a better solution that would be much appreciated! Also a solution to the question I provided would be awesome too, just for learning purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the reason it's failing has nothing to do with the attribute part - it's failing to find the elements at all, as you've asked for just `Compile` elements, whereas there are only actually `Compile` elements in the namespace with the URI `http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003`.

Doing this with XPath probably requires the use of an [`XmlNamespaceManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.xml.xmlnamespacemanager.aspx) which you'd then pass into [another overload of `SelectNodes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4bektfx9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Personally I would use LINQ to XML instead though:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("myfile.xml");
XNamespace ns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003";
var elements = doc.Descendants(ns + "Compile")
                  .Where(x => x.Attribute("Include") != null);
```

In general, I find LINQ to XML to be a *much* cleaner API than the "old" `XmlDocument`-based API.

Comment: How can I use a Count on this? I don't see any XNodeList (or similar) in the XDocument-API. What I am trying to say is, what does this return? A list of elements or?

Comment: @Matthijs: It returns an `IEnumerable<XElement>`. You can use the `Count()` extension method just as with any other sequence. If you want a `List<XElement>`, just add a call to `.ToList()`.